# Hibernate : Why FetchType.LAZY-annotated collection property eagerly loading?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I tried to implement simple `one-to-many` association. after inspecting the item object with debugging mode, I found that `List<Bid> bids` already loaded. But `List<Bid>` bids property is annotated with `FetchType.LAZY`. some books and web pages claim that `FetchType.LAZY` is a hint JPA providers accept or reject. But I wonder on what condition JPA providers ignore `FetchType.LAZY`. Thank you in advance.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ITEM")
public class Item implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Long id = null;

    private String name;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SELLER_ID", nullable = false)
    private User seller;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "item", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Bid> bids;

    /**
     * No-arg constructor for JavaBean tools.
     */
    public Item() {}

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public User getSeller() {
        return seller;
    }

    public void setSeller(User seller) {
        this.seller = seller;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", seller=" + seller +
                ", bids=" + bids +
                '}';
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BID")
public class Bid implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "BID_ID")
    private Long id = null;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Item item;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "BIDDER_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private User bidder;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Item getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(Item item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public User getBidder() {
        return bidder;
    }

    public void setBidder(User bidder) {
        this.bidder = bidder;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Bid{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", bidder=" + bidder +
                '}';
    }
}
```

```
private static void itemSeller(EntityManager em) {

    Item item = em.find(Item.class, 1L);
    System.out.println("hello");

}
```

EDIT : I put break point at the statement `System.out.println("hello")`. I inspected the item object. See the picture :
[image]

Comment: How do you determine that it's loaded eagerly? What's your test?

Comment: 1-N has a DEFAULT of LAZY so specifying it is pointless. What the provider does is specific to your JPA provider (there is no "claim" that it is a hint only ... that is in the JPA spec). The provider I use (DataNucleus) respects what I tell it to use, always. Yours maybe thinks it know better than you? Does it know better than you?

Comment: @NeilStockton Hibernate does of course support lazy loading. And yes, the JPA spec does say that: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html#fetch--.

Comment: By inspecting the object i your debugger, you're asking it to call methods of the list to display its size, content, etc. And that of course initializes the list, lazily. Same for your toString() method, which implicitely loops through the list to print it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

By inspecting the object in your debugger, you're asking it to call methods of the list to display its size, content, etc. And that of course initializes the list, lazily.

Same for your `toString()` method, which implicitely loops through the list to print it.

Comment: I thought my question was like stupid one after seeing your answer. I gave it a thought about deleting this post because of too shame on me. now I am surprised by the number of upvotes and I am happy that even my stupid question came in handy for somebody else. thanks for your answer again.

Comment: @inherithandle there is no need to be ashamed of will learn only when we try, i had the same concern typed on google and  landed on your thread see how  one question can help others. Thanks for asking

Answer (score -1):

As Hibernate docs 
@OneToMany--default fetchType is LAZY
@ManyToOne--default fetchType is EAGER.

If you want to change then fetch=fetchType.LAZY/EAGER

Basically, There are two times of hibernate object 1)Entity Object 2)Valued Object.So in your case Item have a to-many relationship with Bid, If you retrieve Item class at that time hibernate will not fetch related Bid Class record because you did fetch type is LAZY, But you fetch Bid Class record hibernate fetch related Item eagerly for you, because Bid has a ManyToOne relationship with Item class and default fetch type for ManyToOne is EAGER.