# Lazy fetch type doesn't work for identical objects

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

There is User Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    ...
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    public Set<UserPermission> permissions;
}
```

There is permission entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_permissions", indexes = {@Index(unique = true, columnList = "id")})
public class UserPermission {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "target_user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public User targetUser;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "other_entity", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public OtherEntity otherEntity;
}
```

I use this code to fetch user entity:

```
... get session
... open transaction

// fetching user
final User user = session.find(User.class, id);

// fetching permissions
final Set<UserPermission> userPermissions = user.permissions;

// foreach permissions
// HIBERNATE FETCHES HERE targetUser AND EVERYTHING CONNECTED TO THIS ENTITY, LOOKS LIKE FetchType.EAGER

for (UserPermission permission: userPermissions) {
    // there is no code 
}

... close transaction
```

Look at the comment:

```
// HIBERNATE FETCHES HERE targetUser AND EVERYTHING CONNECTED TO THIS ENTITY, LOOKS LIKE FetchType.EAGER
```

It means, that without any calls to targetUser, hibernate fetches it. That's really strange. This behavior really slows down performance of my application.

My assumption: Hibernate just can't proxy two similar objects in one entity (i mean, user and targetUser have the same class, hibernate cannot proxy both objects and thats why it fetches targetUser immediately)

How to solve this problem? Any suggestions?

Comment: What is @Column(nullable = false) above permissions?, maybe that causes this problem!

Comment: I've just removed @Column(nullable = false), but nothing has changed :c

Comment: How do you know entities are eagerly being loaded? have you red this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40437521/hibernate-why-fetchtype-lazy-annotated-collection-property-eagerly-loading?rq=1

Comment: Yes, i've already seen this article, i m using no debuggers or other profiling tools. I wanna sharpen your attention, that "user" and "otherEntity" have "normal" behaviour, so they load only when i use them (normal lazy-fetch behaviour). As for "targetUser", it loads immediately after initializing collection (instead of foreach i could write Hibernate.initialize(userPermissions), the results would be the same)

Comment: I discovered that "targetUser" was being loaded eagerly providing printing hql requests.

Comment: @AntonShadrin Your supposition that recursive relationships cause eager loading isn't correct. What you're describing here isn't the usual behavior of Hibernate, so I'm pretty sure there must be something else going on here that you have not mentioned in your post.